# How to insert the q_auto in cloudinary url from variable in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

I'm having trouble in inserting the "q_auto" in cloudinary variable. I will give some code.

```
let photoUrl = {
   url = https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_600/beach_huts.jpg
}

let finalUrl = ..... some code;
```

I want that in variable finalUrl is like has "q_auto", of course that's only example but lets just say that I don't know the url given my server.How can I do it ?

Comment: let finalUr = `${photoUrl.url}?q_auto=somevalue`. Would be simple as that if you know all your query variables..

Comment: Thank you for answering, I want that the url will be like this. https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/q_auto/w_600/beach_huts.jpg. How can i do that ?

Comment: Why not just replace the "upload/" with "upload/q_auto/"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
let photoUrl = {
   url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_600/beach_huts.jpg'
};
let insertText = 'q_auto/';
let searchText = "res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/";
let position = photoUrl.url.indexOf(searchText);
let insertPosition = position + searchText.length;
var output = [photoUrl.url.slice(0, insertPosition), insertText, photoUrl.url.slice(insertPosition)].join('');

console.log(output);  // https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/q_auto/w_600/beach_huts.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The result bro is like this https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/uploaq_autod/w_600/beach_huts.jpg.

Comment: Can you send the exact code you just ran. 
I believe there is some spelling mismatch in string given.  The answer you just posted can happen only if position = -1 that is the string did not match.

Comment: You can try the code i posted in chrome console to validate the output.

Comment: Yes your right, the position is -1. this is my code
render() {
    let photos = metadata.test.photos;
    
   //photos = http://res.cloudinary.com/test/image/upload/afadsfasf/test.png
    this.test(photos);
}
test = (test) => {
  let insertText = "q_auto";
  let searchText = "http://res.cloudinary.com/test/image/upload/";
  let position = test.indexOf(searchText);
  let insertPosition = position + searchText.length;
  var output = [test.slice(0, insertPosition), insertText, test.slice(insertPosition)].join("");
  
  console.log("output", output);
 }

Comment: its ok already, I adjusted some code, Thank You its working !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for this answer.

```
let photoUrl = {
   url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_600/beach_huts.jpg'
}

var params = {
  param1: 'value1',
  param2: 'value2'
}

let appendedUrl = '';
for(let key in params) {
  if(appendedUrl) { 
    appendedUrl = appendedUrl + '&';
  } else {
    appendedUrl = appendedUrl + '?';   
  }
  appendedUrl = appendedUrl + key + '=' + params[key]
}

let finalUrl = photoUrl.url + appendedUrl;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I want that the url will be like this. https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/q_auto/w_600/beach_huts.jpg. The "q_auto" will be after "/upload/".How can i do that ?